# My render() method is being called while other code is being executed? Swift

Tags: swift, scenekit

I'm creating an app using scenekit, so I'm using:

```
func renderer(_aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: NSTimeInterval) {}
```

as my update method. 
I understand this is being called every frame, but it seems to be called before other code finishes executing. for example the

```
func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {}
```

method.  Before all the code executes here, the renderer() code SEEMS to be executing.  Am I losing my mind or is this actually happening?  If it is, is there a way to call an update method after all other code has been executed?

Comment: You have to understand that in any application there can be lots of threads, which can all execute code at the same time (parallel). So SpriteKit actually uses its own thread to call the render method, which may be started at any time after the window is shown

Comment: so there's no getting around this then?  Damn this is breaking my stuff.  I'll have to work around it somehow.

Comment: Hmm well if it's really the case that it gets executed first, then you can use a `dispatch_semaphore` to let it wait until your other code is done. You'd create one in your class: `let sem = dipatch_semaphore_create(0)`, then on the very end of your code that needs to be executed first: `dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem)` and in your render function: `dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)`

Comment: dispatch_semaphore huh?  I'll check it out.  I realized later that I could just set a bool to true at the end of the code and an if statement in my render function.  This does the trick, but I'll check out dispatch_semaphore, to see what that's all about.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: Oh yeah that would work too of course, much easier